# How can I define a variable in a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drupal-7

I want to use field variable in the below array structure.

```
var field = $(this).attr('field');
alert(Drupal.settings.taxonomy_fancybox.{field});
```

Drupal.settings.taxonomy_fancybox shows the following in the console

```
field_fancybox
:
{vocabulary: "category", node_type: "page", field_name: "field-fancybox"}
field_fancybox_2
:
{vocabulary: "tags", node_type: "page", field_name: "field-fancybox-2"}
```

Comment: `alert(Drupal.settings.taxonomy_fancybox[field]);` I would assume

Comment: ok let me try that and get back to you @mplungjan

Comment: You may have to adjust that somewhat; it's impossible to tell from the console output you've quoted, which is incomplete. But that's fundamentally going to be it. What's inside the `[]` can be any expression, see the linked question's answers for details.